# Bubble notifications in custom app for Microsoft teams

Tags: notifications, microsoft-teams

I am working on developing an app for MS Teams. I want the app to send in-app/bubble notifications to user, to engage the user and draw his/her attention on action item. Could someone please guide how can I make that possible? I am unable to locate documentation for it. I don't want to send messages/ cards in channels via bot.
By "in-app notifications" I mean bubble notification kind of thing which conveys number of messages that are unread in "Chat"/ number of activities under "Bell" icon (currently available in Teams)

Comment: Did you try [Send activity feed notifications to users in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications). Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is with notification under Activity but I want bubble to show on my app, as activity feed notification need some background application level permissions which are not feasible to get , so I want to work with user delegated permissions inside the app only

Comment: Could you please try notification [device permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=desktop#specify-permissions) once? 
Here is some sample I had put together last year: https://github.com/Wajeed-msft/DevicePermissionsDemo/blob/master/DevicePermissionsDemo/Pages/Index.cshtml#L56

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT , the suggestion given above does not send notification in teams app but sends notification in browser

Comment: It doesn't seem to be feasible as per my understanding.